# Regression in data.table in R, id by id (e.g., row by row)

Tags: r, data.table, lm

I am trying to run regressions on a cross section of data. One row (id) will serve as the independent variable for all of the other rows in the data.table. A subset of the columns represent the variables in the regression. A toy example of the data.table setup is as follows (sorry for the awful format):

```
id    xVar1  xVar2  xVar3

ABC    0.05   0.14   0.08

DEF    0.07   0.20   0.09

GHI    0.15   0.18   0.05

JKL    0.06   0.13   0.12
```

For this toy example, the regressions will use variables xVar1, xVar2 and xVar3. In the actual use case, there will be many more columns of data as variables and significantly more rows of id's. Continuing with the toy data, id ABC is the identifier for the columns of data that are the independent variables for each other row in the data.table. The columns xVar1:xVar3 associated with the other id's are the dependent variables.

I have tried the following:

```
testReg <- function(DT){

    x <- DT[id == "ABC", xVar1:xVar3]
    y <- DT[, xVar1:xVar3, by = Symbol]

    for (i in 1 : .N) {

        mod = lm(y ~ x, na.action = na.omit)
        out = sum(mod$residuals[1:11])
        out = ifelse(out < -0.99, -0.99, out)

        DT[, SUM_RESID := out]
    }
}

testReg(DT)
```

I have also tried:

```
x <- DT[id == "ABC", xVar1:xVar3]

DT[id != "ABC", SUM_RESID := sum(summary(lm(xVar1:xVar3 ~ x))$residuals[1:3]), by = id]
```

For both, I get the error message:

> " Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, na.action = na.omit, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'x')"

This makes me suspect that I'm not "pulling" the dependent variable on a row by row basis. I've tried a bunch of different things, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, you would like a model predicting which id based off of xVar1,2, and 3?

Comment: To clarify, you would like a model predicting which id based off of xVar1,2, and 3?

Comment: I would like residuals from regressing xVar1:xVar3 for DEF on xVar1:xVar3 for ABC and then xVar1:xVar3 for GHI on xVar1:xVar3 for ABC. You can think of xVar1, xVar2, xVar3 as time series dates (though they aren't specifically). If I transposed the data.table so that xVar1, xVar2, etc. were rows (like dates) and ids (ABC, DEF, etc) were columns, the problem would be similar to regressing one time series on another, keeping ABC constant as the independent and the other id's (DEF, GHI, etc.) as dependent. Does that help?

Comment: Hey @Mike, it may help if you post an example of your expected output using `datasets::mtcars` or `datasets::iris`